# Different alignment for different rows in eqnarray

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

Please look at this. [image]
I want the continuation parts i.e., row 3 and 5 to be right aligned. I tried to manage by repeated use of `\qquad` but I am sure there must be something better than this. I have used `eqnarray` environment, but am open to any suggestions. Here is the code for this part

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
        g_s(t,s)    &=& E_s x_t^2+2Ex_t x_{ts}+2F_s x_t y_t+2F\left(x_ty_{ts}+x_{ts}y_t\right)+G_sy_t^2+2Gy_ty_{ts} \notag\\
                    &=& \left(E_xx_s+E_yy_s\right)x_t^2+2\left(F_xx_s+F_yy_s\right)x_ty_t+\left(G_xx_s+G_yy_s\right)y_t^2+  \notag\\
                    &&  \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 2Ex_tx_{ts}+2F\left(x_ty_{ts}+x_{ts}y_t\right)+2Gy_ty_{ts}   \notag\\
                    &=& \left(E_xx_t^2+2F_xx_ty_t+G_xy_t^2\right)x_s+\left(E_yx_t^2+2F_yx_ty_t+G_yy_t^2\right)y^s+  \notag\\
                    &&  \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 2\left(Ex_t+Fy_t\right)x_{ts}+2\left(Fx_t+Gy_t\right)y_{ts}  \notag\\
                    &=& Ax_s+By_s+Cx_{ts}+Dy_{ts}   \quad\text{(say).}  \notag
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: *never* use `eqnarray`.

I can propose three different ways to typeset your display. The second seems what you'd like, but it needs to know which one is the longest line (in this case the first). My personal opinion favors to the third way.

I have moved the + to the continuation line, which is more customary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{First way}
\begin{align*}
g_s(t,s)
&=E_s x_t^2+2Ex_t x_{ts}+2F_s x_t y_t+2F(x_ty_{ts}+x_{ts}y_t)+G_sy_t^2+2Gy_ty_{ts}
\\[1ex]
&=\begin{aligned}[t]
  (E_xx_s+E_yy_s)x_t^2+2(F_xx_s+F_yy_s)x_ty_t+(G_xx_s+G_yy_s)y_t^2\\
  {}+2Ex_tx_{ts}+2F\left(x_ty_{ts}+x_{ts}y_t\right)+2Gy_ty_{ts}
  \end{aligned}
\\[1ex]
&=\begin{aligned}[t]
  (E_xx_t^2+2F_xx_ty_t+G_xy_t^2)x_s+(E_yx_t^2+2F_yx_ty_t+G_yy_t^2)y^s \\
  {}+2(Ex_t+Fy_t)x_{ts}+2(Fx_t+Gy_t)y_{ts}
  \end{aligned}
\\[1ex]
&=Ax_s+By_s+Cx_{ts}+Dy_{ts} \quad\text{(say).}
\end{align*}

\subsection*{Second way}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
g_s(t,s)
&=&E_s x_t^2+2Ex_t x_{ts}+2F_s x_t y_t+2F(x_ty_{ts}+x_{ts}y_t)+G_sy_t^2+2Gy_ty_{ts}
\\[1ex]
&=\mathrlap{(E_xx_s+E_yy_s)x_t^2+2(F_xx_s+F_yy_s)x_ty_t+(G_xx_s+G_yy_s)y_t^2}
\\
&&{}+2Ex_tx_{ts}+2F\left(x_ty_{ts}+x_{ts}y_t\right)+2Gy_ty_{ts}
\\[1ex]
&=\mathrlap{(E_xx_t^2+2F_xx_ty_t+G_xy_t^2)x_s+(E_yx_t^2+2F_yx_ty_t+G_yy_t^2)y^s}
\\
&&{}+2(Ex_t+Fy_t)x_{ts}+2(Fx_t+Gy_t)y_{ts}
\\[1ex]
&=\mathrlap{Ax_s+By_s+Cx_{ts}+Dy_{ts} \quad\text{(say).}}
\end{alignat*}

\subsection*{Third way}
\begin{align*}
g_s(t,s)
&=E_s x_t^2+2Ex_t x_{ts}+2F_s x_t y_t+2F(x_ty_{ts}+x_{ts}y_t)+G_sy_t^2+2Gy_ty_{ts}
\\[1ex]
&=(E_xx_s+E_yy_s)x_t^2+2(F_xx_s+F_yy_s)x_ty_t+(G_xx_s+G_yy_s)y_t^2\\
&\qquad{}+2Ex_tx_{ts}+2F\left(x_ty_{ts}+x_{ts}y_t\right)+2Gy_ty_{ts}
\\[1ex]
&=(E_xx_t^2+2F_xx_ty_t+G_xy_t^2)x_s+(E_yx_t^2+2F_yx_ty_t+G_yy_t^2)y^s \\
&\qquad{}+2(Ex_t+Fy_t)x_{ts}+2(Fx_t+Gy_t)y_{ts}
\\[1ex]
&=Ax_s+By_s+Cx_{ts}+Dy_{ts} \quad\text{(say).}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much. Can you please give me some references about the commands you have used here like `\mathrlap`, `[1ex]`, `{}`. I am a novice here and do not have any thorough knowledge.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul `\mathrlap` is a `mathtools` addition: it means “typeset the contents as if it had no width”. The `[1ex]` bit is for inserting additional vertical space, which I think it's better for separating the various parts, because of the continuation lines. Finally, `{}` is for inserting a dummy object for getting the space around `+` correct.